# An open ball is a Jordan region.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I am trying to prove that an open ball $B_r(a)$ in $R^n$ is a Jordan region.

This is a question from Wade's Introduction to Analysis, question 12.1.4 part (b).

To show this, I need to prove that there exists a rectangle R which contains $B_r(a)$ and the volume of the boundary of this ball is 0.

I can see that I can always enclose an open ball by an n dimensional rectangle. But given a $r$, how do I precisely write down this rectangle? Also, I have no idea how to show that its volume is 0.

I also know that a projectable region is a Jordan region. Can I show that an open ball is projectable? Would it suffice as a proof? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: The rectangle that works is $[-a-r,a+r]^{n}$ Why? The distance of the farthest point of the open ball to the origin is $r+a$, then, every point of the ball is in one of this intervals. Then, we know that the boundary of an open ball is $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:||x-a||=r\}$. Suposse that the boundary has volume, then, his interior is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks. I have some trouble imagining that rectangle. $a$ is a vector whereas $r$ is a real number. How do I make sense of $a+r$?

Comment: Sorry. Consider the canonical directions with the factor $r$. The idea is to proyect the open ball over the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the volume of the boundary $S$ is zero, consider the region between two balls centered at $a$ given by  $$V_\epsilon = \{x: r - \epsilon \leqslant \|x-a\| \leqslant r + \epsilon\}$$  We have $S \subset V_\epsilon \subset R$ where $R$ is a rectangle enclosing the outer ball defining $V_\epsilon$.

Hence,

$$vol(S) = \int_R \chi_S \leqslant \int_R \chi_{V_\epsilon} = vol(V_\epsilon).$$

The volume of a ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $C_nr^n$ where $C_n$ is a constant . The volume of $V_\epsilon$ is then the difference between the volumes of two balls and is given by

$$vol(V_\epsilon) = C_n(r+ \epsilon)^n - C_n(r - \epsilon)^n = 2nC_n\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).$$

Thus,

$$vol(S) \leqslant 2nC_n \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ can be arbitrarily small it follows that $vol(S) = 0$.

Another approach is to show that the surface $S$ has measure $0$ by producing for any $\epsilon > 0$ a cover by rectangles with total volume less than $\epsilon.$  For general $n > 3$ this is quite complicated.

See, for example, [here](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%2010.pdf?...).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This was most helpful. I understand that I can find $vol(V_\epsilon)$ by Binomial theorem, etc. But I haven't seen that big O notation. Could you please explain what $O(\epsilon^2)$ is? Is it a remainder term in $(\epsilon^2)$?

Comment: You're welcome.  The notation $f(\epsilon) = O(\epsilon^2)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ means that there are constants $C>0$ and $\alpha > 0$ such that $|f(\epsilon)| \leqslant C\epsilon^2$ for $\epsilon \in (-\alpha,\alpha)$. Then we have $f(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.  For example, $\epsilon^3 = O(\epsilon^2)$.  In this case all the other terms of the expansion can be collected into something that is $O(\epsilon^2)$ and, of course, be neglected for our purpose of showing $vol(S) = 0.$

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772852/volume-of-disjoint-union)?

Comment: @Gord452: I'll take a look.

Comment: thank you so much!